# Symmetric Group and Alternating Subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that $A_{4}$ is the only subgroup of $S_{4}$ of order $12$.

-So far I know that the best way to prove this is by contradiction, assuming that there exists another subgroup in $S_{4}$ of order $12$:
Suppose $H$ is an subgroup of $S_{4}$ of order $12$. Since the order of $S_{4}$ is $24$, the index of $H$ is $24/12=2$.

What next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a subgroup of $H$ (of order 12) in $S_4$ is of index 2, it must be normal.

This means it must be a union of conjugacy classes: if an element belongs to $H$ so does all of its conjugates.

In $S_4$ all of the transpositions are conjugate: $\{ (12),(13),(14),(23),(24),(34)\}$ (6 of them). The 3 cycles are all conjugate: $\{ (123),(132),(124),(142),(134),(143),(234),(243)\}$ (8 of them). The 4 cycles are all conjugate: $\{ (1234),...\}$ ($(4-1)!=6$ of them). The disjoint pairs of transpositions are conjugate: $\{(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$ (3 of them). Finally, the identity is just conjugate to itself.

We get: 6+8+6+3+1=24.

Now if some element is in a normal subgroup, everyone of its conjugates must be in there too. So a normal subgroup can be decomposed into the disjoint union of conjugacy classes. Keeping in mind, the identity must belong to any subgroup, how can we get 12 out of these numbers: 1,3,6,6,8? Just one way: 1+3+8. This exactly corresponds to the even permutations. :)

**Another Approach** Show that any subgroup of $S_n$ is either all-even or half-even/half-odd (hint: if not all-even, pick an odd member and use this to get a bijection between the even and odd elements in the subgroup).

Next, assume that we have a subgroup of order $n!/2$ which isn't $A_n$, call this $H$. Then $H$ is half-even/half-odd. Therefore, $A_n \cap H$ is a subgroup of $A_n$ of index 2.

But $A_n$ doesn't have subgroups of index 2. $A_2$ and $A_3$ are of orders 1 and 3 so they can't have a subgroups of orders 0.5 and 1.5 (silly). $A_n$, $n \geq 5$, doesn't have a subgroup of index 2, since such a subgroup would be normal and $A_n$ is simple (no non-trivial normal subgroups) for $n \geq 5$.

This just leaves $n=4$, the case you're actually interested in. In this case $A_4$ would have to have a subgroup of order 6. It doesn't. Why not? Brute force check. :(

So in the end, the only subgroup of order $n!/2$ in $S_n$ is $A_n$ (for any $n$).

Comment: "Since a subgroup of H (of order 12) in $S_{4}$ is of index 2, it must be normal." Why is that so?

Comment: Any index 2 subgroup is normal. Why? Let $H$ have index 2 in $G$. Then its left cosets are $H$ and everything left over (i.e. $G-H$ the set complement of $H$ in $G$). Now the right cosets must be $H$ and again everything that is left-over: $G-H$. Therefore, the left and right cosets match (i.e. $H$ is normal).  The key is that when $H$ has index 2, there isn't any room for the left/right cosets to be mismatched. :)

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $A_4$ is the group of even permutations in $S_4$. For any $x\in S_4$, $x^{-1}A_4x$ is a conjugate subgroup of $A_4$ and is also order 12. Can this subgroup have odd permutations? Can there be any subgroup of $S_4$ of order 12 with odd permutations? The minimal generating set for $A_4$ is 2 transpositions (odd $\times$ odd = even) and an even 3-cycle. Could an order 12 subgroup with an odd 3-cycle contain the identity (even permutation)?

Change in approach based upon whacka's comments. Thanks!

Comment: How do we go from $A_4$ being normal to $S_4$ having no other subgroups of the same order as $A_4$?

Comment: @whacka: We don't. My hint does not mention normality, and neither does the question. It characterizes the elements of $A_4$. With that, Bill Cook's answer is nice!

Comment: The answer to your question is "no, no conjugate of $A_4$ contains odd permutations" (which is more or less saying $A_4$ is normal); how are we expected to go from that to the desired conclusion? Perhaps there is something obvious which I am not seeing.

Comment: @whacka: As soon as posted my last comment I realized you are correct. Any subgroup of order 12 is of course normal, but I have not shown it to be a conjugate of $A_4$. Pardon!